# PhoneGap deviceready not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Please check my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phoneGap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("searchbutton", myfunction, false);
    }

    function myfunction() {
        alert("hello");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to `alert("hello");`, but it is not working. I am just starting with android apps using PhoneGap-2.9.0 and I am running into a lots of problems. Please help.

***Edit***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap Device Ready Example</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phoneGap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        alert('this is device ready function');
        document.addEventListener("click", myfunction, false);
    }

    function myfunction() {
        alert("hello");
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="myfunction();">Click 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="onDeviceReady();">Click 2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please check above code and let me know why `Click 2` is now working in emulator?

Comment: you need to replace `phonegap.js` with `cordova.js` and check whether the file exist in the **www** folder in the phonegap app.

Comment: How do you know that device ready is not working? fire alert inside device ready, not inside searchbutton listener - probably searchbutton listener is not working rather than deviceready itself

Comment: I have not include jquey.min file. this js file is required or not?

Comment: @frank I am just adding `cordova.js` still not working.

Comment: With the code you're using, you have to press the search button to call the function. And by the way if you're starting why not use cordova 3.5?

Comment: @QuickFix Can you give me a small example how to alert `hello` message when will click the button.

Comment: In the example you use deviceready adds a listener for a press on the physical search button of the phone and displays an alert in this case. Since the button does not exist on most android phones, I'm not sure it's what you're trying to do. Use `backbutton` instead and your alert should appear when you press the back button on your phone.

Comment: @learnphp :Try by including Jquery library as you mentioned you did not included `jquey.min file` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`document.addEventListener("click", myfunction, false);` 

to
`document.addEventListener("click", myfunction, true);`